# Where to give client_max_body_size 2M; in nginx.conf file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, server, passenger

I have mentioned this in my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;    
        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # Phusion Passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
    ##

    passenger_root /home/dinshaw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.56;
    passenger_ruby /home/dinshaw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby;
    client_max_body_size 2M;
    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

     include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
     include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        server {
           rails_env development;
           listen 80;
           server_name localhost;
           root /home/dinshaw/projects/freeway/freeway-sdk-portal/public;
           access_log /home/dinshaw/projects/freeway/freeway-sdk-portal/log/nginx_access.log;
           error_log /home/dinshaw/projects/freeway/freeway-sdk-portal/log/nginx_error.log;
           passenger_enabled on;
         }
}


# mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# }
```

And there is no effect after this I had this outside the server i.e like this also :

```
passenger_root /home/dinshaw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.56;
passenger_ruby /home/dinshaw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby;


server {
    rails_env development;
    client_max_body_size 2M; 
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /home/dinshaw/projects/myCode/public;
    access_log /home/dinshaw/projects/myCode/log/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /home/dinshaw/projects/myCode/log/nginx_error.log;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

But this is also not working If am uploading more than this also it is not giving error. My

```
 nginx version: nginx/1.6.3
```

Please guide me its about more than 2 days am working on it and not getting what to do.

Comment: Your first configuration should be ok. Have you restarted nginx after changes?

Comment: yes I have restarted and reloaded the server but nothing happens:(

Comment: is the above the whole nginx config?

Comment: edited my question this is my whole setting

Comment: When you say it's not giving error, do you mean it lets you upload files bigger than 2M or that it stops completely and shows nothing?

Answer (score 1):

What you have done by putting the client_max_body_size inside both your http {} and server {} brackets is micro-define your client_max_body_size.

NGINX works by basically nesting control settings, the outer most shell being http {} -> server {} -> location {}. So, what this means is that if you set something in http {}, it is applied to server {} and location {}. But if you set something in server {}, it will only apply to that server {} and not to http {}.

*note*: always, whenever you make some changes to your nginx.conf file, you must restart your nginx server (as @ihsan suggested above):

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

What you've done here is a good try, but you've defined the same thing twice so it shouldn't make much of a difference if it didn't work the first time.

I have run into this issue many times, and aside from changing your nginx.conf file to allow your max size to be 2M, you also need to change your php.ini file to allow you a certain size to upload (2M I guess?).

Inside your php.ini file you will find something that looks like:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

You must also change these limits to match your expected upload file size. How big you go is your choice, but remember, the bigger you set this limit, the more opportunity you are giving spammers or server bullies to upload big files to your server, thus taking up precious space and bandwidth.

Finally, if you monitor your NGINX error.log, you should be able to see the exact process that's restricting your upload. You enable your error.log within your http {} or server {} brackets, as:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
```

Reminder though, that setting your log level to warn will make very big files (especially if you have lots of virtual servers running), so it's suggested to only keep it like this when you're troubleshooting perhaps, and then turning it back to higher errors only.

For more information on how to monitor NGINX errors, read here: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/

Hope this helps!